# JSON Decoding UUID String to UUID Object

Tags: swift

For some weird reason when decoding JSON which contains the UUID as String, the resultant UUID property is always coming to be nil.

[image]

UPDATE:

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    var id: UUID?
    var title: String
    var poster: String
```

UPDATE:

This is unbelievable. Debugger was lying the value was NOT NULL.

Comment: Are you sure the id you are decoding is an actual UUID and not something that looks like a UUID? Also your break point is before the UUID has been decoded, perhaps having the break point on line 29 would be better.

Comment: Most probably [UUID.init?(uuidString: String)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid/1411662-init) fails to create the UUID object.

Comment: @Andrew I am stepping through and checking it at the end of the init. Still self.id is nil. The weird part is that if I take the same code and paste it on the terminal it works as expected.

Comment: `UUID` conforms to `Decodable`. You might be able to decode it directly.

Comment: @vadian That is what I tried and it failed. The data is coming from JSON so in JSON it does not know what UUID type is. It is sent back as String thats why I am having to manually convert to UUID.

Comment: INSANE! The debugger is lying. The value was NOT null.

Comment: I mean `self.id = try decodeIfPresent(UUID.self, ...`

Comment: Software Never Lies™

Comment: I feel your pain, though.

Comment: I had to print the value on the screen and found out it was NEVER nil. I noticed this before and this bug has been going on for couple of years now.